# "1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax" when LOAD DATA INFILE with fields specification

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064, load-data-infile

I've spend several hours reading probably over 10 different Q&As on this website and reviewing my following query many times and still couldn't find what the problem is. This is my query definition line in my `PHP` codes:

```
$q="LOAD DATA INFILE '$filename' 
    IGNORE INTO TABLE `temp_data_1` 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '\\' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 
    LINES (`field_1`, `field_2`, `field_3`, `field_4`, `field_5`, 
            `field_6`, `field_8`, `field_9`) 
        SET `field_7` = SUBSTRING_INDEX(`field_6`, '.',-1)";
```

`$filename` is set after uploading the `CSV` file. Pretty similar code works in `phpMyAdmin` but I cannot make it work in my `PHP` codes. I keep getting this error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' IGNORE 1 LINES (`field_1`, `field_2`, `field_3`, `field_4`, `field_5`, `field_6`, ' at line 2

I suspect it's related to `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'` but I don't see any problem with it, as that exact same line termination definition is working in some other part of the code.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You also need to escape in the string in PHP, otherwise the escape sequences get interpolated there.

Comment: You mean scaping `'\r\n'` as `'\\r\\n'`?

Comment: Yes. And for the other \ too.

Comment: I'll test, but aren't the others already escaped?

Comment: @stickybit, your suggestion didn't work and now it give this error: `1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES`

Comment: One time yes. But you need to escape them two times. Once for PHP once for MySQL.

Comment: Because `'\\'` isn't escaped in PHP MySQL gets `'\'`. The second single quote is escaped, so it thinks `'\' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '` is a string literal.

Comment: Like `'\\\"'`, `'\\\\'`, & `'\\\r\\\n'`? If so, it's very weird to me and never have done it like that. Also the other part of the code is doing it correctly.

Comment: Just `'\\r\\n'` for the last one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple test, just write a little script and run it in the CLI to see what gets output from your string.

```
$filename = 'dsafsdf';

$q="LOAD DATA INFILE '$filename' 
    IGNORE INTO TABLE `temp_data_1` 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\\\"' ESCAPED BY '\\\' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\\r\\n' IGNORE 1 
    LINES (`field_1`, `field_2`, `field_3`, `field_4`, `field_5`, 
            `field_6`, `field_8`, `field_9`) 
        SET `field_7` = SUBSTRING_INDEX(`field_6`, '.',-1)";
echo $q;
```

The output is

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'dsafsdf' 
    IGNORE INTO TABLE `temp_data_1` 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '
' IGNORE 1 
    LINES (`field_1`, `field_2`, `field_3`, `field_4`, `field_5`, 
            `field_6`, `field_8`, `field_9`) 
        SET `field_7` = SUBSTRING_INDEX(`field_6`, '.',-1)
```

Note the missing `\` which have been interpreted as excape chars because you are in a double quoted string. So all you need to do now is add the relevant number of escapes to get the correct output like this

```
$q="LOAD DATA INFILE '$filename' 
    IGNORE INTO TABLE `temp_data_1` 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\\\"' ESCAPED BY '\\\' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\\r\\n' IGNORE 1 
    LINES (`field_1`, `field_2`, `field_3`, `field_4`, `field_5`, 
            `field_6`, `field_8`, `field_9`) 
        SET `field_7` = SUBSTRING_INDEX(`field_6`, '.',-1)";
echo $q;
```

Generates what was expected

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'dsafsdf' 
    IGNORE INTO TABLE `temp_data_1` 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '\\' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 
    LINES (`field_1`, `field_2`, `field_3`, `field_4`, `field_5`, 
            `field_6`, `field_8`, `field_9`) 
        SET `field_7` = SUBSTRING_INDEX(`field_6`, '.',-1)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I'm confused why the other code I have somewhere else is working correctly. I double checked it right now and it was not escaped as you're suggesting here. Anyway, problem solved and many thanks for it.